# Endomorphism of a group

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

Let $G$ be a group with presentation 
$$G=\langle x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_k\colon R_1(x_1,\cdots,x_k)=1, \cdots, R_n(x_1,\cdots,x_k)=1\rangle.$$
Here $R_i(x_1,\cdots,x_k)$ denotes a word in $x_1,\cdots,x_k$.

Suppose $y_1,y_2,\cdots,y_k$ are elements of $G$ such that in $G$, $$R_i(y_1,\cdots,y_k)=1.$$

**Question:** Does the map $x_i\mapsto y_i$ extends to homomorphism (endomorphism) of $G$?

I was thinking YES; but unable to give clear justification. Any suggestion on problem?

Comment: Are you familiar with how presentations work in terms of free groups, together with the universal property of free groups?

Comment: I know universal property of free groups. I am familiar a little with free groups etc.

Comment: So $G = F_k/N$ where $N$ is the normal subgroup generated by the relations. Your condition means that all the $y_j$ are in $N$.

Comment: you mean $R(y_1,\cdots, y_k)$ are in $N$. is it?

Comment: Google "Dyck's Theorem" perhaps.

Comment: Right, sorry. Do you see how to proceed?

Comment: OK; perhaps this way. From free group $F=\langle X_1,\cdots, X_k\rangle$ to $G$ there is homomorphism, and its kernel is normal closure of words $R_i(X_1,\cdots, X_k)$. Next, how?

Comment: Consider the composition of the maps $F\to F$ and $F\to G$ where the first sends $x_i$ to $y_i$ and the second projects to the quotient. Now show that $N$ is in the kernel of the composition, making it a map from $G$ to $G$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if $h : A \to B$ is a group morphism, then

$$
h(R_i(a_1,\dots,a_n)) = R_i(h(a_1),\dots,h(a_n)).
$$

for any $a_1, \dots, a_n \in A$. Now, the function between sets

$$
f : x_i \in \{x_1,\dots,x_n\} \mapsto y_i \in G
$$

induces a group morpshism which I will note with the same name

$$
\begin{align}
f : F(x_1,\dots,x_n) \to G
\end{align}
$$

and moreover we have $f(x_i) = y_i$. By our first observation, we have that

$$
f(R_i(x_1,\dots,x_n)) = R_i(f(x_1),\dots,f(x_n)) = R_i(y_1,\dots,y_1) = 1,
$$

and so $f$ factors through the quotient

$$
\begin{align}
&F(x_1,\dots,x_n)/\langle\langle R_i(x_1,\dots,x_n) \rangle\rangle_{i \in \{1,\dots,n\}} \\
&=\langle x_1,\dots,x_n | R_i(x_1,\dots,x_n) = 1, 1 \leq i \leq n\}\\&= G.
\end{align}
$$

(The elements $x_i \in G$ are the images of each $x_i$ in the free group, i.e. formally in $G$ we have the classes $[x_i]$ of each element, and thus $\bar{f}(x_i)$ is notation for $\bar{f}(q(x_i))$ with $q$ the canonical projection.)

Therefore, there exists a morphism $\bar{f} : G \to G$ such that

$$
\bar{f}(x_i) = f(x_i) = y_i
$$

as desired.